# Build a tree from related objects

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I need to build this tree:

```
result = [
  ['t9'],
  ['t3',   
    ['t4'],
    ['t8',   
      ['t6'],
      ['t1',
        ['t5']
      ]
    ]
  ],
  ['t7',
    ['t2']
  ]
]
```

from these objects:

```
{:id => 't1', :tg => 't8', :rank => 2}
{:id => 't2', :tg => 't7', :rank => 1}
{:id => 't3', :tg => nil, :rank => 2}
{:id => 't4', :tg => 't3', :rank => 1}
{:id => 't5', :tg => 't1', :rank => 1}
{:id => 't6', :tg => 't8', :rank => 1}
{:id => 't7', :tg => nil, :rank => 3}
{:id => 't8', :tg => 't3', :rank => 2}
{:id => 't9', :tg => nil, :rank => 1}
```

`tg` is the self referential association.
`rank` is the position/index in the array

Any ideas (preferred in ruby)?

Comment: Can you express yourself better? `result` simply does not look like a multidimensional array...

Comment: What you claim as "th[e]s[e] objects" are not Ruby objects. And what are `t1`, `t2`, etc.? How would you expect the information from the objects to be passed to a method?

Comment: @sawa I simplified the list of objects for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def combine e, a
  a
  .inject([]){|a, h| a[h[:rank] - 1] = [h[:id]] if h[:tg] == e; a}
  .map{|e| e + combine(e.first, a)}
end

combine(nil, [
  {:id => 't1', :tg => 't8', :rank => 2},
  {:id => 't2', :tg => 't7', :rank => 1},
  {:id => 't3', :tg => nil, :rank => 2},
  {:id => 't4', :tg => 't3', :rank => 1},
  {:id => 't5', :tg => 't1', :rank => 1},
  {:id => 't6', :tg => 't8', :rank => 1},
  {:id => 't7', :tg => nil, :rank => 3},
  {:id => 't8', :tg => 't3', :rank => 2},
  {:id => 't9', :tg => nil, :rank => 1},
])
# => [["t9"], ["t3", ["t4"], ["t8", ["t6"], ["t1", ["t5"]]]], ["t7", ["t2"]]]
```

Comment: That's sawa at his best. You figured it, congrats! @AlexLopez: Don't forget to accept the chosen answer!

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are building up something like a tree. the algorithm can be concluded as follow:

1. find all node where :tg is nil, then you get [t3, t7, t9]
2. find all the nodes whose :tg inside the [t3, t7, t9], then get back [t4, t8]
3. find all the nodes whose :tg inside [t4, t8]
   ...

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion (based on @cenyongh's tree concept)

```
def tree(arr,parent=nil)
    arr.select{|n| n[:tg] == parent}.
            sort_by{|n| n[:rank]}.
            map{|n| [n[:id]] +  tree(arr,n[:id])}
end

# call
tree(array_of_objects)
```